# Populate reference object which is also a reference object mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a schema called Message, defined likewise:

```
const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     name : {type : String}
});

module.exports('Message',messageSchema);
```

I have another schema called Topic, which uses 'Message' as a reference object.

```
const topicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    topics : { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Message' }
});

module.exports('Topic',topicSchema);
```

I have a schema called Thread, which uses an array of 'Topic' object references.

```
const threadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    thread : [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Topic' }],
    name : {type : String}
});

module.exports('Thread',threadSchema);
```

How to access all the 'Message' elements if we have a 'Thread' document with us?

I tried doing the following:

```
Thread.findOne({name : 'Climate'}).populate('thread').populate('topics').exec(function(err,data){})
```

but I am getting errors since *thread* population has an array. Please help in correctly dereferencing the *message* object.

Comment: There seem to be some mistakes in the code provided. In your `topicSchema`, for example, you are exporting `messageSchema`. Also in `threadSchema`, you are referencing the `Thread` itself again? If these are just copy-paste typos then please correct them first so that examples of your schemas are valid.

Comment: Apologies @JakubASuplicki. Those are simple copy-paste typos. I have changed the question to reflect your comments. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigations, I was able to solve the problem. An easy solution not involving nested `exec` statements is described.

```
const myThread = await Thread.find({name : "Climate"}).populate('thread');
//This populates the 'thread' component of the Thread model, which is essentially an array of 'Topic' elements.
```

Since we have populated the 'thread' field as an array, we can iterate through each member of that field, populating the 'topic' field present with the base 'message' model.

```
const myTopic = myThread.thread;
for(let i = 0; i < myTopic.length ; i++)
{
    myCurrentTopic = myTopic[i];
    var myTopicPopulated = await Topic.find({_id : myCurrentTopic._id}).populate('topic');
    //Do further processing

}
```

This is a simple way to handle such cases, without resorting to usage of the `path` proxy.

Comment: Have you tried the nested population suggested in my answer?

Comment: @JakubASuplicki I did try it. While it worked fine for simply nested models, it didn't seem to work if the underlying model referred to an array of objects, like in my example. Perhaps my implementation was wrong, but I felt this approach to be simple.

Comment: Personally, I would not recommend this solution as it requires multiple requests to the database that could ideally be handled by using a nested `population` that is optimised to handles such scenarios and reduces the performance hit of doing it manually like this. That is one of the advantages of using subdocument references. If not that then even `$lookup` with `pipeline` would be much more efficient.

Comment: Understood. I did feel the responses were a little slow. I will try this out and let you know how it works out.